# Snowflake: how to truncate data if larger than column size while loading?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

How can I truncate the column data when it's size is greater than the column size while loading it into a Snowflake table. I am using file format to do COPY INTO as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT 'schema."csv_file_format"'
                  TYPE = 'csv'
                  FIELD_DELIMITER = '\001'
                  NULL_IF = ('\\N', 'NULL', 'NUL', '')
                  COMPRESSION = 'AUTO';

COPY INTO schema.table_name
FROM @EXTERNAL_STAGE/s3_prefix
FILE_FORMAT = 'schema."csv_file_format"' ON_ERROR = 'CONTINUE' PURGE = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are copy options (ENFORCE_LENGTH, TRUNCATECOLUMNS) for CSV data

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#copy-options-copyoptions

Answer (score 1):

For CSV files Snowflake provides column ordering, column omission using SELECT statement and setting TRUNCATECOLUMS=true|false in COPY command.

For more information refer [Transforming Data during dataload](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-transform.html#transforming-csv-data)

Comment: thanks for the answer, TRUNCATECOLUMS is applicable just for CSV or any fileformat?

Comment: @Vishrant Only CSV

Comment: Thanks @Zonera that's helpful.